# media queries only work on devtools but not on devices

Tags: css, css3, layout-responsivo

I made a project with simple html and css and added some media queries.(my resolution is 1980x1080)
It turns out that when I set for example 1366x768 (which is a common resolution for notebooks) in DevTools everything looks perfect.
However, when the client opens it on his laptop at home, it is not exactly as I defined it.
I took a notebook with the same resolution (1366x768) and it gave the same problem.
I'm working with a lot of images and texts positioned absolutely from these images so any 10 pixels hurts me.
I would like to understand how I can solve this problem and how I can develop viewing a screen that is not mine but that works.
I tested using the Responsively app but it appears as it does on my computer, everything is perfect.
Can you help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Importante [editar sua postagem original conforme já orientado lá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/576283/70). Para evitar desencontro de informações, o espaço de comentários desta postagem foi desativado, mas continua funcional na postagem original.